# Can only access 2.2GB of internal storage from Windows

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, internal-storage

Anyone have any thoughts about this:

It seems to me that when the phone's internal storage is mounted using the Mass Storage mode, Windows only sees the first 2.2GB of space. If I try to format it using Windows, I only get an option to create a 2.2GB FAT32 partition. If I format using the Captivate's formatting tool, it creates a 13.03GB partition. Now the fun part:

The Captivate seems to be able to read/write from the whole 13GB partition fine. However, Windows seems to be only to access the first 2GB of that 13GB partition. While I can see all the files listed, trying to read from file that were created after the first 2GB returns an error, and trying to copy additional files from windows to the internal storage once the 2GB limit is reached results in an error.

Using Kies, I was able to copy files from the internal storage that were stored past the 2GB barrier.

Anyone have any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with various Galaxy S models after upgrading to 2.2.  I don't think anyone's found the cause, but this fix should work (did for me on my Vibrant) and is relatively simple.  Make sure to do a backup first if you want, preferably using ClockworkMOD / Nandroid, because this will wipe out everything except your external SD card.  And make sure you have good drivers installed.

1. Download stock 2.2 firmware, such as from [this XDA post for AT&T](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=11526718&postcount=1) (first link) or [this XDA post for Rogers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=905042) (first link, "Odin Flashable").  Do not unzip it.
2. [Download Odin](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=8863727&postcount=1) (for Windows.  If you have no access to Windows, use [Heimdall](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=755265) and modify steps 4+ accordingly).
3. [Download the 512 PIT file](https://content.wuala.com/contents/Samsung%20Galaxy%20S/Firewares%20,%20Updates%20and%20Odin/Odin%20&%20.PIT/s1_odin_20100512.pit?key=AfzUZSU4SpKU&dl=1).
4. Put your phone into download mode:

   1. Take out the battery.
   2. Attach the phone to your computer via USB.
   3. Press and hold both volume buttons.  While holding:

      1. Insert the battery.
      2. Click the power button.
      3. Wait for download mode to show up (yellow triangle with an android in it).
5. Start Odin.
6. Load the firmware .zip file into the PDA field of Odin.
7. Load the 512 PIT file into the PIT field of Odin.
8. Ensure "Re-partition" is checked.
9. Make sure Odin shows your device connected (Yellow box with text something like "0:[COM1]").  If not, disconnect the phone from USB and immediately re-connect.
10. Click Start.
11. Wait till Odin says it's done, then disconnect your phone.  Or if Odin shows an error, reboot your phone and start from step 4 again.  (Sometimes this just happens).

Comment: Thanks Matt. Forgot to put this in my original post. I'm running the official Froyo build on a Rogers Captivate (I896), non rooted. Do I have to root my phone to be able to apply your fix above?

Comment: Nope, no rooting required.  Odin is the tool Samsung uses internally for loading software on the devices; it works even on "bricked" phones.

Comment: Just wanted to say I haven't had a chance to try this out yet, but I did call Rogers tech support, and they acknowledged that this is a known issue, and their work around at this point is to used Kies to pull data on and off. Haven't tried with an external SD card yet to see if the issue is there as well.