# How to hard reset of a Samsung Galaxy GT-I9000 which I cannot put in recovery mode?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, factory-reset, recovery-mode

I don't have much hope. Here is what's happening

Galaxy S GT-I9000 keeps crashing at startup :
 
com.sec.android.provider.logprovider crashes 
and other ones android.process.acore
 

 
So I cannot reach any settings to disable some system settings like Settings/Privacy
 
So I cannot connect usb (it's never seen by my PC)
 

 
And a very good joke : it cannot be put in recovery mode !
http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_Series#Recovery_Mode
 
Does nothing

Somebody have notices some i9000 in this case :
http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/fix-3-button-combo-download-recovery-mode-in-samsung-galaxy-s-gt-i9000/
Too bad I can't do this : "Now plug the USB cable into the phone. Start a new command prompt window and navigate to the folder/directory where you have installed ADB."
As my phone is not able to make the usb work !

So is there a way to reset the phone the hard way ?
 
I mean by opening it and erasing the memory to revert to an empty phone fully ...

PS : I cannot tell the android installed on this phone. It's not mine. All I know is that it's pretty old and that it's a custom "Orange" ROM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your help
I can confirm that :

- I had a rom (from Orange France) without any way to put my phone in download mode
- The little device here http://galaxy-download-mode.blogspot.ch/ works
- I was then able to upgrade my GT-I9000
- And now Home+Vol down + power works (so not download mode was not an hardware issue)

Comment: now I am upgrading my phone from 2.3.6 to ... (I don't know yet I'll what version the phone can hold)

Comment: total non-sense device, don't buy it

Comment: I know that it looks like total non-sense.  But IT WORKED

Comment: you can access the recovery modes with volume+home+power, just switching between volume up ad down does sometimes the trick

Comment: I know that.  I tried that but this recovery WAS NOT available with the rom installed

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this:

1. Turn the power off. If your Samsung Galaxy S is frozen, pull the battery out and reinsert it
2. Hold the Volume Down button
3. Press and release the Power button
4. You are now presented with a menu that allows for Fastbook, Recovery, Clear Storage, and Simlock
5. Select Clear Storage by pressing the Volume Down button
6. Press and release the Power button
7. Now simply confirm your decision: Volume Up for YES and Volume Down for NO

(Source: [KnowYourCell.Com](http://www.knowyourcell.com/samsung/samsunggalaxys/galaxy-s-guides/498616/how_to_hard_reset_the_samsung_galaxy_s.html) -- the first hit on a little [Google Search](http://www.google.de/search?q="factory+reset"+galaxy+s))

---

**UPDATE:** Alternative approaches are listed at [Hard-Reset.COM](http://www.hard-reset.com/samsung-i9000-galaxy-s-hard-reset.html), e.g.:

1. charge your battery fully before doing a hard reset
2. PRESS AND HOLD VOLUME UP + Home Button (or VOLUME UP + DOWN)
3. Keep pressing these 2 buttons + press Power button for 2-3 Seconds
4. Release only power button, but KEEP pressing Volume up + Home Buttons (or VOL UP + DOWN)

---

You also might check with the following question here: [SGS doesn't go to download, recovery mode nor does it connect via USB after installing a battery MOD](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7379/)

Comment: It doesn't : the phone simply starts and boot.  I am going to try this trick https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjDkShT-65Y

Comment: I just edited my answer and added a second approach (and source). Maybe you have more luck with that.

Comment: `Volume UP + Home` and `power for 3 seconds` helped me get into recovery.

Comment: That was "Option 3" from my last update – thanks for confirmation, @OstapAndrusiv!